# Goodreads data protection clarification

Tags: ipad, applications, encryption

I'm using the **Goodreads** iPad app. I have data protection set in the iPads general settings and passcode required to unlock. I also have a passcode to open Goodreads.

My understanding is that when the iPad is locked, files are encrypted (at least the ones in the Goodreads folder, but not other files?) I'm wondering if even when the iPad is unlocked if the files in the Goodreads folder are protected if Goodreads is not loaded and asking for the passphrase.

I'm guessing based on my understanding of the manual, but hopefully I'm wrong.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My earlier answer was incorrect. iOS 4 does incorporate file system level encryption - impressive!

The answer to your question is here:

> It is important to understand that GoodReader itself doesn't encrypt
>   or decrypt your files. It does two things - restricts the access to
>   protected files via GoodReader's own user interface, and asks iOS to
>   encrypt certain files (or all of them, if you're using app startup
>   password). iOS, in its turn, locks these files within a few seconds
>   after you lock your device with a passcode, and instantly unlocks them
>   when you unlock your device with a passcode. It means that when you
>   unlock your device with a passcode, all your files become decrypted
>   and fully accessible, even if GoodReader app is not being run at the
>   moment, and you haven't entered any of GoodReader's passwords yet. So,
>   if your device is unlocked, GoodReader will prevent the access to
>   protected files via its own user interface, but nothing prevents from
>   copying these files via, for example, File Sharing section of iTunes
>   (USB transfer), without knowing GoodReader's passwords. So please be
>   sure to ALWAYS lock your device with a passcode, even if you leave it
>   just for a minute. This will turn the physical hardware-based
>   protection on. And while Auto-Lock option in main device Settings may
>   be of great help with this, it never hurts to manually lock your
>   device every time you leave it.

From:

http://www.goodiware.com/gr-man-general.html#dataprot

Put concisely, while the iPad is unlocked all data is unencrypted, so in principle, hackers could access your files during this time.